# Tensor flow has no attribute elu (exponential linear unit)

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow, activation-function

I have been using tensor flow to implement a neural network, but I am not sure what is happening but I am getting this error message:

```
h1=tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(X,w_h1)+b_h1)  
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'elu'
```

If I replace `tf.nn.elu(tf.matmul(X,w_h1)+b_h1)` by `tf.nn.relu(tf.matmul(X,w_h1)+b_h1)` it works well.

However, the activation function `elu` is listed [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.12/api_docs/python/nn/activation_functions_).

Does anybody know what must be happening?

Comment: Is your TensorFlow version older than 0.6? In this case you might fix it with an upgrade (this error has been reported here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/495).

Comment: How do I know the version? I think it is up to date. But I am not sure. I tried print tensorflow.__version__ but it does not have this attribute.

Comment: Then it is probably an old one. I recommend upgrading to a newer version and checking whether the issue still exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

the error must happened by tensorflow's version